# What effect does a graphics card have on live streaming output?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, streaming

I stream live events, with the cameras inputted through USB adapters, and the stream encoded with WireCast.

How much of an effect does the graphics card have on the output quality when live streaming? That is, if I'm building a desktop, do I need to make sure I have a stellar graphics card, or does it not really matter much?

I assume that it does not matter much, and that the CPU is the one doing all the work.

Comment: This depends mostly on the software you're using.  Some of the nicer/more-expensive packages offload most of the video-processing to the GPU leaving the CPU more-or-less idle... whereas cheaper solutions just throw everything at the CPU.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is over 10 years old and effectively abandoned and the self-solved answer provides a [forum link](http://forum.telestream.net/forum/messageview.aspx?catid=44&threadid=9545) that is now dead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@TheCompWiz comment](https://superuser.com/questions/422153/what-effect-does-a-graphics-card-have-on-live-streaming-output#comment483308_422153), I did research on Wirecast specifically, and based on [this answer thread on Wirecast's support forums](http://forum.telestream.net/forum/messageview.aspx?catid=44&threadid=9545), WireCast can and does significantly use the GPU.

Comment: The link to that [Wirecast forum post](http://forum.telestream.net/forum/messageview.aspx?catid=44&threadid=9545) is dead. The forum “expired.” This is why we ask that all links to other sites also provide info on what is in that link here. That way if the link dies, the content still lives here.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience in live streaming for years, GPU always assigned to do graphics things rather than CPU. For my case, at first, I found my CPU stayed peek at 100% out of the time with internal Intel graphics card to do a live broadcast. Quite interesting result when I loaded a new **1050Ti graphics card with 4GB of RAM**, it leaves my CPU at around 10 percent constantly with the same kind of broadcast.